# How to fix node gyp error caused by new macos catalina update

Tags: node.js, xcode, macos-catalina, node-gyp

I updated my mac's os to catalina `10.15.4` after that node-gyp started to complain saying

> gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what has happened But I did following and it started working back again

Remove command line tools

`sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Then reinstall

`xcode-select --install`

Hope this helps everyone who has faced the same issue as me

Comment: You can find the path of installed command line tools by `xcode-select --print-path`

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you may have tried multiple solutions so far but if none of those solutions have worked for you yet, don't worry - I got you. :)

**Non-working Solutions:**

1. `xcode-select --install` didn't work for me (macOS Catalina 10.15.7) as it shows up a Software Update dialog box which says `Can't install the software because it is currently not available from the Software Update Server`.
2. I also downloaded and install Xcode Command Line Tools from Apple's download website (https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode) but the problem re-appeared somehow or may be it didn't solve it in first place and I somehow didn't notice.
3. `sudo xcode-select --reset` also didn't do the trick for me.

**Working Solution:**

Here is what worked for me i.e. reinstall Xcode Command Line Tools using Software Update manually.

1. Check if Command Line Tools Update is mentioned in your list of softwares to be updated by using following command: `softwareupdate -l`
2. If Command Line Tools Update is not mentioned in that list, then manually make it part of the list using following command which will create a temporary file: `sudo touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress`
3. Verify that the list now has the Command Line Tools mentioned by running `softwareupdate -l` again.
4. Now, press Cmd+Space to initiate Mac's Spotlight Search. Search for `Software Update`. Start the `Software Update`.
5. That will show you following kind of dialog for installing the Command Line Tools. Install away the update and be merry. :)
   [image]
6. Remove the temporary file created in Step 2: `sudo rm /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress`.